# How to get the response from post request in array instead of object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying with laravel controller to get data with condition.

First, i got all the data "orders" from my data base.

```
public function getAllInternOrders(Request $request)
    {
        $userData = $request;

         $orders = InternOrders::all();

         $sortedOrders = $this->sortOrdersBasedOnUserRole($orders, $userData);

        return response()->json($sortedOrders);
    }
```

Then, in a private function I sort the data "orders" and return them.
userData is an object with multiples values.
userName is a string .
userRole is an array with multiple or one value.

```
    private function sortOrdersBasedOnUserRole($orders, $userData)
{
    $sortedOrders = null;
    $userName = $userData->get('displayName');
    $userRole = $userData->get('userRole');

    if (in_array("1", $userRole)) {
         $sortedOrders  = $orders->where('Referent', $userName);
    } elseif (in_array("2", $userRole)) {
         $sortedOrders = $orders->where('Status', '>', 0);
    } elseif (in_array("3", $userRole)) {
         $sortedOrders = $orders->where('Status', 2)->orWhere('Status', 3);
    }
    return $sortedOrders;
}
```

My problem :

When I enter in the first condition, everything is ok. I got my data in an array.
When I enter in the second condition, I got no error but my data is inside an object (instead of an array like the first condition).
When I enter in the condition number three, I got an empty array and the error "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orWhere does not exist."

What I have already try :

- to add "->get();" in the end for the $sortedOrders.
- I have seen that the error for "orWhere" is because "orders" is an object instead of an array, but I have also tried to convert orders into an array but still got the same error.
- I have seen in stack over flow post,that I am returning a response inside a response but i have tried to render response()->json() but still got the error
- I have tried to convert the response in my front end into an array. It is working for condition 1 and 2 but not for the condition number three who still have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor your code. When you get Order::all() -> you retrieve a collection instead of query, so you are performing where() on collection.
Try something like this :

```
public function getAllInternOrders(Request $request)
{
    $userData = $request;

    $sortedOrders = $this->getOrdersBasedOnUserRole($userData);

    return response()->json($sortedOrders);
}


private function getOrdersBasedOnUserRole($userData)
{
    $userName = $userData->get('displayName');
    $userRole = $userData->get('userRole');

    if (in_array("1", $userRole)) {
         $sortedOrders  = InternOrders::where('Referent', $userName);
    } elseif (in_array("2", $userRole)) {
         $sortedOrders = InternOrders::where('Status', '>', 0);
    } elseif (in_array("3", $userRole)) {
         $sortedOrders = InternOrders::where('Status', 2)->orWhere('Status', 3);
    }
    return $sortedOrders->get()->toArray(); //convert to array for json.
}
```

Also i advise you to validate request before using variables $userName and $userRole and rename InternOrders into singular name InternOrder.

Comment: Working fine! thank you so much, I am new to php and laravel so it was not obvious for me. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

When you do $orders = InternOrders::all(), $orders is a collection. So, you can't call orWhere method because collection doesn't have that method.

You should call where and orWhere method of Builder. You can consider doing like below:

```
public function getAllInternOrders(Request $request)
{
    $userData = $request;
    $sortedOrders = $this->sortOrdersBasedOnUserRole($userData);

    return response()->json($sortedOrders);
}

private function sortOrdersBasedOnUserRole($userData)
{
    $userName = $userData->get('displayName');
    $userRole = $userData->get('userRole');

    $query = InternOrders::query();
    
    if (in_array("1", $userRole)) {
        $query->where('Referent', $userName);
    } elseif (in_array("2", $userRole)) {
        $query->where('Status', '>', 0);
    } elseif (in_array("3", $userRole)) {
        $query->where('Status', 2)->orWhere('Status', 3);
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```